# Let an application play an 3GPP audio file

Tags: android, file, audio

I recorded a 3GPP Audio file and would like my Android app to Play it when I tap on a certain button. I must save the file in res/raw, mustn't I?

Which code do I Need?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what library you want to use.

Comment: It should work with Android 4.1+, I don't want to give the ability to stop it or something like that, simply a quick code on how to Play the file please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this..

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mymusic);
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In android you cannot save file inside the apk file (in res,raw,..etc) , but you may save it to a location in sd card for e.g Android/com.yourpackage.appname/sound.3gpp 

After that setup a MediaPlayer and let it play the sound you recorded & stored previously.

```
File soundFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.mp3");
Uri soundUri = Uri.fromFile(soundFile );
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundFile );

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Hope this is clear to you